# Why my ForEach execute without be called ? ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a ForEach inside a function, and it performs even if it is not called, so it renders the screen.

What I am trying to do is: When I click on the `startGame` function, the element of the array that is in position [1] is 5, but as soon as it renders the screen it already starts as 6.

And the `finishGame` function I want when I click I want it to be displayed 6, but it already gets like 6 before I even clicked the function.

startGame:

```js
startGame = () => {
  this.state.cardsDealer.forEach(function(i, index, array) {
    if (index === 1) {
      array[1] = '6'
    }
  })
}
```

```js
finishGame = () => {
    this.state.cardsDealer.forEach(function(i, index, array) {
      if (index === 1) {
        array[1] = '5'
      }
    })
```

Does anyone know why? Or if the way I'm doing is wrong, for what I want?

Comment: If it was called - it was called. "Or if the way I'm doing is wrong" --- you must not directly mutate the `this.state` object.

Comment: Do you by any chance call `startGame` in the `render` ? Also a `for` to change the first index of the array is pointless, just do `array[1] = '6'`. No need for any `for`

Comment: Yes, i know but i dont know do, without be like this..

Comment: You should use `this.setState` instead. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#an-interactive-component

Comment: How i would can do this by this.setState?

Comment: @Isac I'm not saying what they do makes much sense, but replacing their forEach with just an assignment would change the semantics: what if the array is empty or just 1 element long?

Comment: @Jota have you checked through the link I provided?

Comment: @zerkms That's fair. Although you can still check for that with an `if`, and it would still be better than using a `for` to always set  the same item.

Comment: You are not showing how you link up the event handlers, so there is not much we can say. Please read [mcve].

Comment: **it performs even if it is not called** That's impossible. The function must be getting called, you just don't understand why. And the question doesn't provide enough information to answer it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
startGame() {
  this.state.cardsDealer.forEach(function(i, index, array) {
    if (index === 1) {
      array[1] = '6'
    }
  })
}
```

Try it

Comment: What did the OP do wrong? What did you change? Why does it work? "Try it" is not an answer.

Comment: It's better to explain what you have done, not just dump code.

Comment: This isn't valid syntax for a function definition, unless it's part of an object literal (in which case it's short for `startGame: function() { ... }`)

Comment: I just encountered this situation, but I'm not quite sure why.

For example, these two pieces of code, the first piece of code will automatically trigger when it runs, I think it may be related to this? , I am still looking for answers, but also please know the students to answer, thank you

test = () => {
   console.log(1);
}
render () {
  <div onClick={this.test()}></div>
}


test() {
  console.log(2);
}
render() {
  <div onClick={this.test.bind(this)}></div>
}